# Broadcast from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to modify a form in a view by means of a button in my directive's template (template is in another file), this is for a basic CRUD where each item has a delete/edit button.

In order to avoid replicating the form I decided to that on edit's click a function would send the item to the controller in questions in order to be updated with the new information.

But I've been having troubles making the connection, so far I tried changing `$root`, to `$rootScope` back and forth and using , `$broadcast` or `$emit`.

So how can I send the function onChange my item's information based on the template's button click?

**Template:**

```
<strong>{{item.type}}</strong> {{item.description}}

<div class="material-switch pull-right">


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle"  ng-show="item.editable" ng-click="onChange()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ></span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" ng-controller="View1Ctrl" ng-show="item.editable" ng-click="EliminarItem(item)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></span>
    </button>


    <input ng-model="item.isDone" 
        id="someSwitchOptionDefault{{itemIndex}}" 
        name="someSwitchOption001{{itemIndex}}" 
        type="checkbox" /> 
        <label for="someSwitchOptionDefault{{itemIndex}}" class="label-info"></label>
</div>
```

**Directive**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.items.directive', [])

.directive('itemSwitch', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            itemIndex: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/itemSwitchTemplate.html',
        link : function($scope){
            $scope.$broadcast('onChange', item);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','itemsService',function($scope,itemsService) {
    $scope.items = itemsService.getItems();
    $scope.classMap = {GROCERIES:"success",CAR:"danger",UNIVERSITY:"warning",PAYMENTS:"info"};
    $scope.newItem = {};


    $scope.$on('onChange', function(event, args) {

        if ($scope.btnEdit) {

             $scope.newItem = args;
        } else {
             $scope.newItem = {};
        } 

    });


    $scope.enableEdit = function (item) {

                item.editable = true;
            };

    $scope.disableEdit = function (item) {

                item.editable = false;

            };

}]);
```

**View**

```
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div ng-model="currentItem" ng-repeat="item in items" item-switch item="item" item-index="$index" class="notice notice-{{classMap[item.type]}}" ng-mouseover="enableEdit(item)" ng-mouseleave="disableEdit(item)">
            </div>


<!-- FORMULARIO -->

    <form name = "myForm" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="legend">
          <legend class="">Task</legend>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <!-- Name-->
          <label class="control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="itemName" ng-model="newItem.name" placeholder="Task Name" class="input-xlarge"  ng-required="true" >
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <!-- Description -->
          <label class="control-label">Description</label>
          <div class="controls" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.description" placeholder="Task Description" class="input-xlarge">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="controls">
            <a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addOrSaveItem()">
            <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-save img-circle text-success"></span>Save</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

        </div>
```

[FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvt4s/74/)

Look nd Feel

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "onChange" as an event name is a poor choice as it is likely to conflict with other events with that name. My recommendation is to use the directive's name as part of the event name.

### In your directive

```
angular.module('myApp.items.directive', [])

.directive('itemSwitch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            itemIndex: "="
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="doIt()">Do It</button>',
        link : function(scope){
            scope.doIt = function() {
                scope.$emit('itemSwitch.doIt', scope.item, scope.itemIndex);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

### In your controller

```
$scope.doItItems = [];
$scope.$on("itemSwitch.doIt", function(item, itemIndex) {
     doItItems.push(item);
});
```

In this example, on each click of the `Do It` button, an item is pushed to the `doItItems` list.

Answer (score 0):

In your `itemSwitch` directive, you can do

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('onChange', item);
```

And then you can pick it up in any scope that is listening (in this case, your controller), with

```
$scope.$on('onChange', function(event, args) { ... }
```

This works because `$broadcast` moves downward from parent to children, while `$emit` moves upward from child to parents.

So for example, `$rootScope.$emit` would only be picked up by `$rootScope.$on` since `$rootScope` has no parents, while `$scope.$broadcast` would only be available to that scope's children and not to `$rootScope.$on`, since `$rootScope` is not a child of `$scope`